# Pi can't ping internet from terminal but have access for chrome and package managers

Tags: raspbian, networking, dns

I'm trying to simply git clone some repo so I can work on it on the raspberry pi. I try

`git clone git@github:the/repo/place`

but it returns with

`ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: No route to host`

and this isn't github specific since `ping 8.8.8.8` or pinging google will return `destination unreachable` from terminal. What's strange is that I can use the Chromium Web Browser and connect to anywhere on internet just fine. What's even weirder is although pinging doesn't work, I can do `sudo apt-get install something` or `pip install somemodule` and it also just works fine.

The raspberry pi is setup so that it's connected to some hardware device via ethernet with static Ethernet ip set on raspberry pi so that it can communicate with the device. I'm remoting into this raspberrypi via NoMachine on wifi LAN but I doubt it's the nomachine causing the issue but some network setup.

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall allowing port TCP 443/80 but blocking TCP 22 and ICMP?

Comment: Shouldn't your command line be "git clone git@github.com:the/repo/place"?

Comment: @DouglasLeeder I can ssh into the raspberry pi so port 22 is open.

Comment: @HiredMind You're right, I just wrote it down off top of my head here but the command that was actually used was correct.

Comment: Seems only your `ping` program isn't working. Try with `sudo ping google..com` and `chromium-browser google.com`. What is the result?